# Can same GraphQL Subscription be called in different screens?

Tags: graphql

Hello folks I came across something strange working with GraphQL Subscriptions. So I have the following subscription in 3 different screens because of document type that use must upload.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!nextProps.getKYCDocuments.loading) {
      let { subscribeToMore } = this.props.getKYCDocuments;
      subscribeToMore({
        document: KYC_ADDED,
        variables: {
          user: this.props.getMe.me._id
        },
        updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
          if (!subscriptionData.data) {
            return prev;
          }

          const kycAdded = subscriptionData.data.kycAdded;

          if (
            !prev.getKYCDocumentsForThisUser.find(d => d._id === kycAdded._id)
          ) {
            return {
              ...prev,
              getKYCDocumentsForThisUser: [
                { ...kycAdded },
                ...prev.getKYCDocumentsForThisUser
              ]
            };
          }
          return prev;
        },
        onError: err => console.log(err)
      });
    }
}
```

this is what I have in my resolver

```
pubsub.publish(KYC_ADDED, { [KYC_ADDED]: KYCToUpdate });

kycAdded: {
    subscribe: withFilter(
      () => pubsub.asyncIterator(KYC_ADDED),
      (payload, args) => {
        return payload.kycAdded.user === args.user;
      }
    )
  },
```

Now, when I am going to `Kyc Document One` screen I am making a mutation to create first document. Subscription is working well. I go back and then go to `Kyc Document Two` screen. I am doing the same thing but there is no subscription response coming back. Checked the DB and the object of my mutation is there. Now I am refreshing the app an select `Kyc Document Two` screen making the mutation and the subscription response is there. going back and then to `Kyc Document One` screen making the mutation and no subscription response